# Pyodbc - Login Failed for user - Confirmed user information is correct and working

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am connecting to an SQL server.  This application was working last week. The server lost power over the weekend and shutdown. I came in this morning and turned everything on, and now I cannot connect to the SQL server.

When I open SQL Server management configuration and use the username and login specified in my connection string it allows me to connect and access the database without issue. But doing it through python/pyodbc (again, without changing any code that was working last week) I get the following error.

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'Warehouse'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'Warehouse'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")

The connection string I am using is:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'Driver={driver_name}; '
                       'Server=192.168.1.x\SERVER-NAME\SQLEXPRESS,1433;'
                       'Database=Warehouse;'
                       'Integrated Security=False;'
                       'Trusted_Connection=no;'
                       'UID=Warehouse;'
                       'PWD=passwordhere;'
                       'pool_pre_ping=True;'
                       'pool_recycle=3600;',
                        timeout=1
                      )
```

I have restarted the VM the SQL server is hosted on and it did not resolve it. Any help is appreciated.

edit:
I have my python application set to re-attempt to connect to the SQL server every ~5 minutes, so that if the connection ever times out (which is does after a while) it will re-initiate the connection. Could the warehouse user be blocked somehow over the network after too many failed login attempts to the server while it was offline?

Comment: The error is telling you that there's an invalid attribute, not that the credentials are incorrect. `192.168.1.x\SERVER-NAME`  doesn't look right either; you need to use the server name *or* the IP, not both.

Comment: @Larnu When I remove the IP address and only use the servername it gives me the same error, saying the login failed for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the SQL Server Configuration Manager, the TCP Port was reset to something in the 4x,xxx range. I set it to 1433 like it was before and everything works now.